# How do I join the data from multiple excel cells to make one list and then remove the duplicates?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, list

I want to take the data from multiple excel cells and concatenate it so that it is one big string.

example of original strings in a cell 1 and 2:

Cell1 :

```
the_red_bucket_01, the_blue_duck_01,_the green_banana_02, the orange_bear_01
```

Cell2 :

```
the_purple_chair_01, the_blue_coyote_01,_the green_banana_02, the orange_bear_01
```

I want the new list to look like this, each item being its own string object within a list. Once the data is joined into one big list, I want to separate each item in the list into it's own object, by separating each after the comma:

```
the_red_bucket_01
the_blue_duck_01
the green_banana_02
the orange_bear_01
the_red_chair_01
the_blue_coyote_01
the green_banana_02
the orange_bear_01
```

Then I want to remove duplicates so that the console only shows 1 of each item, no matter how many there are of them.

Right now my code treats each cell as two separate lists, although each object within the list is separate.

For example if I want the first item in the list, it returns the first item in cell1 AND cell2, while I just want one big list and one item returned.
 I can't seem to get my foreach/if statements to work. .

```
 List<string> fn = new List<string>();

                foreach (Excel.Range itemo in xlRng)
                {
                    string itemString = (string)itemo.Text;

                    fn.AddRange((from each in itemString.Split(',')
                                 select each.Trim()).ToArray<string>());

                }
                foreach (string combo in fn.Distinct())
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(combo);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each cell you create another list, so previous items disappear. Because you named the variable `fn` doesn't make it the same in each iteration. `new` operator creates a new references each step.
To make a persistent list, just move list initialization before `foreach`.

```
List<string> fn = new List<string>();
foreach (Excel.Range item in xlRng){...}
```

Inside foreach, use list's `AddRange` function add the result from `split` function.
And this is how you get a big list.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, it makes a lot of sense, thanks! Was just wondering what an example of the AddRange function would be.. the stuff I've googled, I'm not sure what variables to use with it.

Comment: I edited my code, yet it is still returning both lists with duplicates

Comment: Move second `foreach` outside the first one.

Comment: Tried that,edited code, it's still returning the same values :(. The reason I know it's treating both cells as separate lists is because when I do ... fn.First(); to get the first value of the list it returns the first item in Cell1 and the first item in Cell2 together